# NSAttributedString from HTML in the background thread

Tags: html, ios, ios7, nsattributedstring

What I need is to create `NSAttributedString` objects from relatively big HTML strings and store them (NSAttributedString-s) in the database. And of course I would like to do that in the background thread.

Here is a simple code (which fails) to demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSString *HTMLString = @"<p>HTML string</p>";
    NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute : @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[HTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:options documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
});
```

According to [this discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910101216/http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/327998-does-initwithhtml-datausingencoding-documentattributes-run-an-event-loop.html) it might not be possible to do it in the background thread at all, since creating `NSAttributedString` with `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` option uses `WebKit` which requires spinning the runloop while any asynchronous work is performed.

But may be someone else figured out the way? I have pretty simple HTMLs, just text and links, may be there is a way to specify that creating a `NSAttributedString` from the HTML will not require any "`WebKit`-rendering"?

Or may be someone can recommend a third-party lib to create `NSAttributedString`s from simple HTMLs that does not use `WebKit`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can't it in a background thread only on main thread.
Use Oliver Drobnik's  `NSAttributedString+HTML` class.

Code would be something like this -

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:<html> dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] documentAttributes:nil];
```

Link - https://github.com/InfiniteLoopDK/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML/blob/master/Classes/NSAttributedString%2BHTML.m

Answer (score 1):

You can try [NSAttributedString+DDHTML](https://github.com/dbowen/NSAttributedString-DDHTML). AFAIK it doesn't depend on WebKit and I used it successfully for simple HTMLs. I haven't tried using it in the background thread, but I suppose it shouldn't be a problem.

And watch out - it may crash when HTML includes font which is unavailable on iOS. I've issued a [pull request](https://github.com/dbowen/NSAttributedString-DDHTML/pull/2) for that.

Comment: Anyone confirmed whether or not it works on the background thread?