# NSString remove html tags, keep <Text in angle brackets>

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsstring

How do I remove html tags from NSString, but keep any `<Text in angle brackets>`?

Like `<p>123 <Hello> abc</p>` -> `123 <Hello> abc`

I have tried all kinds of regexp, scanner and XML Parser solutions, but they remove `<Text in angle brackets>` as well as tags.

The only solution that fit me was to use an NSAttributedString with options

```
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:utf8Data
                                                               options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                         NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                    documentAttributes:nil
                                                                 error:nil];

NSString *result = [str string];
```

but this approach employs WebKit and consumes too much memory for my task.

So, how do I strip tags from NSString, keeping `<Text in angle brackets>` without using any kind of WebKit/UIWebView and so on?

Comment: Is "Text in angle brackets" always the same? If not, how do you determine that you have to keep "Text in angle brackets" and not "p" (for example)? In other words, how to know what text inside angle brackets are tags or not?

Comment: FYI - The text in angle brackets isn't valid HTML or valid XML. The `<` should be `&lt;` and the `>` should be `&gt;`. Otherwise there is no way to differentiate tags from text in angle brackets.

Comment: You could have a regex that looks for all HTML tags and just strips those out. Something like this `\<(a|img|div|...)[^\>]*\>` of course it'll match <a monkey lives here>

Comment: @Larme no, it is not the same. I get it from web in CDATA as user input from WYSIWYG. But how does WebKit separate <Text in angle brackets> from markup?

Comment: @rmaddy nice hint, will dig it

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/74815 for more information about parsing HTML with regex.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559011/nsattributedstring-from-html-in-the-background-thread)ma while ago, may be some of the answers can help you out.
If you do need the full HTML parser and just want to strip HTML tags out, a `NSString` category might be useful (this one is a modified category by mwaterfal):

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingTags {

    // Find first & and short-cut if we can
    NSUInteger ampIndex = [self rangeOfString:@"<" options:NSLiteralSearch].location;
    if (ampIndex == NSNotFound) {
        return [NSString stringWithString:self]; // return copy of string as no tags found
    }

    // Scan and find all tags
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
    NSMutableSet *tags = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    NSString *tag;
    do {
        // Scan up to <
        tag = nil;
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&tag];

        if (tag) {
            NSString *t = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@>", tag];
            [tags addObject:t];
        }

    } while (![scanner isAtEnd]);
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:self];
    NSString *finalString;

    NSString *replacement;
    for (NSString *t in tags) {
        replacement = @" ";
        if ([t isEqualToString:@"<a>"] ||
            [t isEqualToString:@"</a>"] ||
            [t isEqualToString:@"<span>"] ||
            [t isEqualToString:@"</span>"] ||
            [t isEqualToString:@"<strong>"] ||
            [t isEqualToString:@"</strong>"] ||
            [t isEqualToString:@"<em>"] ||
            [t isEqualToString:@"</em>"]) {
            replacement = @"";
        }
        [result replaceOccurrencesOfString:t
                            withString:replacement
                               options:NSLiteralSearch
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, result.length)];
    }

    // Remove multi-spaces and line breaks
    return = [result stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace];
}
```